# counting rows that have join matches

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In a MySQL database, I have two tables.  I need to count how many rows in `tbl1` have matches in `tbl2`.  Here is the simplified relevant table structure:

```
tbl1  
    code (pk)
    label  

tbl2  
    id  
    code1 (fk to tbl1.code if there is a match for a given row)  
    reltype
```

I have the following sql to start with:

```
SELECT code, label FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.code=tbl2.code1  
WHERE reltype='desiredtype';
```

I think this tells me how many rows in `tbl2` have matches in tbl1.  Is this correct?  Also, the reason for my posting is, **how can I change this to determine how many rows in `tbl1` have matches in `tbl2`?**

Comment: Can tbl2 have more than one match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(*) from tbl1 
where code in (select code1 from tbl2)
```

perhaps?  Might need `distinct(code1)` for optimisation.

Comment: +1 This should return the specified result (aside from the criteria on the reltype column). The `IN (subquery)` can be a real performance hog in MySQL, because of the way MySQL processes the subquery for each row returned by the outer query. There are more efficient approaches. (It's not clear whether OP criteria on `reltype` should be included or not.)

Comment: @Chrisky +1 and thank you.  This runs in less than 2 seconds on a very large data file.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(tbl1.code) 
FROM 
    tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.code=tbl2.code1  
WHERE 
    tbl2.reltype='desiredtype'
GROUP BY 
    tbl1.code
```

Comment: Thank you for being the first responder.  I ran your query, and it gives 8 times the number of rows in tbl1.  I want a number that works out to somewhere between 0% and 100% of the total number of rows in tbl1.  How do I amend your code to accomplish this?

Comment: Glad to help you. I've changed the query, have a check.

Comment: +1 and thank you.  Your amended code prints out all of the rows that match instead of a count number.  But the number of rows is the same as the count number produced by crisky's code.  Your code takes three and a half minutes to run, while his version gives the same number in less than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(t1.code) Cnt
FROM tbl1 T1
  JOIN tbl1 T2
     ON T1.code = T2.code1
WHERE T2.reltype='desiredtype'
GROUP BY T1.code
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct. Inner joins provide if there are unique matches in both tbl1 and tbl2.

```
SELECT tb1.code, tb1.label FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.code=tbl2.code1  
WHERE reltype='desiredtype';
```

You can use left joins or right joins in a different case.

Comment: This doesn't return the count of rows from `tbl1` that have a matching row in `tbl2`.

Comment: @spencer7593 you can use the count()  method to get number of rows as in the other answers

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches.

Given that you have a PRIMARY KEY in tbl1, you can do a query similar to yours, but add a `GROUP BY tbl1.pk`, to eliminate duplicates, and reference that query as an inline view to get a count of the rows returned by that query. (That's not the most efficient approach.)

If you just want a count, then you could modify your query to do a `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tbl1.pk)`. The `DISTINCT` modifier inside the `COUNT()` aggregate counts only unique values, that is, any duplicated values of the expression do not get included in the `COUNT()`. This likely the most efficient approach:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tbl1.code)
  FROM tbl1
  JOIN tbl2 
    ON tbl2.code1 = tbl1.code  
   AND tbl2.reltype='desiredtype';
```

---

There several other alternatives. One way is to join to an inline view that gets a distinct list from tbl2, e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM tbl1 
  JOIN (SELECT tbl2.code1
          FROM tbl2
         WHERE tbl2.reltype = 'desiredtype'
         GROUP BY tbl2.code1
       ) d
    ON d.code1 = tbl1.code
```